# Choppy linear gradient in Chrome

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

The background of the center pane renders great in IE and Mozilla but has a choppy left band in Chrome. Here is the CSS:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(58, 58, 58, 1) 0px, #dbdbdb 2%);
```

You can look at the site live at http://www.ingyenpiac.com

Please help!

Comment: If you're not concerned about IE older than 9, transform:rotate should yield better-rendered results (TRANSPARENT angled gradients can indeed get choppy or get gaps at gradient joins).